# Length of perpendicular vector

Tags: vectors

The points A and B have position vectors, relative to the origin $O$, given by $\overrightarrow {OA} = i + j+ k$ and $\overrightarrow {OB} = 2i + 3k$. The line $l$ has vector equation $r = 2i -2j -k + \mu(-i +2j +k)$.

$i)$ Show that the line passing through A and B does not intersect $l$.

$ii)$ Show that the length of the perpendicular from A to $l$ is $\frac {1}{\sqrt 2}$.

I did part $i$, how do I do part $ii$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C$ be the point on line $l$ which is the shortest distance from $A$. This is the perpendicular. $C$ has co-ordinates given by $2\vec i-2\vec j-\vec k+\mu_0(-\vec i+2\vec j+\vec k)=(2-\mu_0)\vec i+(2\mu_0-2)\vec j+(\mu_0-1)\vec k$ for some $\mu_0$ which we must determine.

To minimise the distance we minimise the distance between $C$ and $A$:$$\begin{align}|C-A|^2 = & (2-\mu_0-1)^2+(2\mu_0-2-1)^2+(\mu_0-1-1)^2 \\ 
& = {\mu_0}^2-2\mu_0+1+4{\mu_0}^2-12\mu_0+9+{\mu_0}^2-4\mu_0+4\\
& = 6{\mu_0}^2-18\mu_0+14\\
\end{align}$$
This is a quadratic. To minimise, we differentiate and set the derivative equal to zero, which gives: $$12\mu_0-18=0\implies\mu_0=3/2\\\implies |C-A|^2=6\cdot{\frac32}^2-18\cdot\frac32+14=\frac12\\\implies|C-A|=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$

Comment: That quadratic has a negative square root, where did $12\mu - 18 = 0$ come from?

Comment: Differentiation - to find the minimum of the quadratic, differentiate and set the derivative equal to zero.

Comment: I used that to minimise the quadratic. Alternatively you could compute the axis of symmetry of the quadratic, which is $$-\frac{b}{2a}=\frac{18}{12}=\frac32$$ as before. This is basically the same calculation regardless.

Answer (score 0):

We can assume a point on the line l 
A vector can be formed by the points on the line and the point A 
This vectors would be perpendicular to line l 
Thus the dot product must be zero.
After finding the points on l .we can use the distance formula and find the perpendicular distance.

Comment: Can you use this example with numbers, so I can understand it better please?

Comment: Like if a point on the L is (2,3,4) . Then AL vector can be written as. (2-1,3-1,4-1) or (1,2,3) as AL vector would be perpendicular to the direction ratios of the line. Their dot product would be zero. Thus point (2,3,4) is a point on line L which is the minimum distance from Point A which is the perpendicular distance. Use distance formula to find the distance between A and L this is the perpendicular distance

Comment: I still don't quite get it, so what do I do in this example??

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the equation of the line as
$$r = (2-\mu)i + (2\mu-2)j + (u-1)k$$
You can get all the position vectors from origin to any point lying on the line by varying the value of $\mu$.

Point A is $(1, 1, 1)$, let point P be $(2-\mu, 2\mu-2, \mu-1)$.

Find the distance between these two points, it will be a quadratic equation in $\mu$. Find the minimum value of that quadratic equation, it will be the perpendicular distance from A to $l$.

Answer (score 0):

By point i) you have demonstrated that the two lines do not intersect.
Now, either they are parallel or they are *skew*.

If parallel, take a point on each of them (A,B) and do the cross product with the unit vector parallel to the lines.

If skew, there will be two parallel planes, each containing one of the lines.
The vector normal to both planes will be given by the cross product of the vectors parallel to the lines.
Find the two planes with such normal vector that contain the lines (it is sufficient to impose that they contain one point which is on the line).
The distance between the lines will the distance between such planes, which you are supposed to know how to compute.